# refresh value in a popover

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a countdown in a Popover. The countdown lasts 1 minute. The problem is that when I display the popover, the countdown always resets to 1 min and repeats the countdown.

I execute [self setimer] in the viewdidload method.

```
-(void)countdown{

 seconds = seconds - 1;
 static int minutes;
 minutes = seconds / 60;
 static int secondes;
  secondes = seconds - (minutes * 60);

 NSString *timeroutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.d:%2d", minutes, secondes];
 countdown_label.text = timeroutput;

 if (seconds == 0) {
    [countdown_timer invalidate];
    countdown_timer = nil;

 }
}

-(void) setTimer{
    seconds = 1500;
    countdown_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

NSString *identifier = segue.identifier;
if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"popover_time"]) {
    UIViewController *dvc = segue.destinationViewController;
    UIPopoverPresentationController *ppc = dvc.popoverPresentationController;
    if (ppc) {
        if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) { // Assumes the popover is being triggered by a UIButton
            ppc.sourceView = (UIButton *)sender;
            ppc.sourceRect = [(UIButton *)sender bounds];
        }
        ppc.delegate = self;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Show the code for where you create the popover.  The `-viewDidLoad` method gets called every time you load the view controller (`-initWithNibName`, etc), so I suspect you are calling your `setTimer` method each time you display the popover

Comment: I add an aswer with the creation code of the popover ! Thanks !

Comment: Please edit the original question and add the requested code.  Only post an answer when answering the question. Welcome to StackOverflow.  Take the tour to learn how to use the site:  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: It's OK !! I edit the original question